# Race condition with Windows sockets

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, tcp

I have a strange problem which occurs only with some specific Windows versions (unfortunately I do not have such a Windows variant but only bug reports from a user which can see this problem).

What I'm doing: I send data via TCP/IP from a client application (on a PC) to an embedded device. This is a continuous stream of data out of one threads context and here always a bunch of data are collected so that the packages have a size of a bit less of multiples of 1460 bytes to have as most as effective TCP-packets.

Now a stop-condition can occur, where one has to react immediately. In this case an other TCP-package is sent to the device using the same network connection but out of an other thread. This package contains a payload of only a few bytes but is sent 3..4 times to ensure reaction of the device.

Both threads use the same sending-function, but it is locked by a mutex so that no concurrent accesses can happen.

Now following problem occurs on this one users PC: when stop-packages have been sent, all following send-attempts to the same socket fail with a system error code of 10054 (remote end hung up). Amazingly the log files of the embedded device clearly say the connection was not closed by it.

Since I can't reproduce this problem, I stab in the dark here.

The problem appears only on this users Windows 7, it does not happen with Linux or with my Windows versions (including a Windows 7). Thus any idea/suggestion/comment is welcome: are there any bugs/conditions known where a Windows TCP/IP connection can fail in this way?

Thanks for every comment and idea!

Comment: 10054 is `WSAECONNRESET`. Unless you, or an intermediate router/firewall, is closing the socket, the device has to be doing it, despite what its log says. The content of the messages is irrelevant, that is not what causes connection resets. You told the device to stop something, so it stopped, most likely incorrectly, ending up resetting the connection as a result.

Comment: Also, TCP guarantees message delivery and integrity, so you shouldn't have to send a stop message multiple times just to get the device's attention. That would only be needed in UDP, but not in TCP. If you are worried about any delays in the socket transmitting the stop message, you could enable the socket's `TCP_NODELAY` option to avoid that.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau the device deifnitely is not closing the connection - I have the hands on the firmware and therefore can verify this. And stop transmitted several times not because of the TCP-connection but because of the device, to ensure it definitely, surely, absolutely surely was not in a state where perhaps, accidentially one stop was ignored for some strange reason.

Comment: Wireshark / procmon will typically help.

Comment: @Sergei Vorobiev cool idea but the problem happens not on my side but only at one user - which is not able to deal with WireShark :-/

Comment: Then procmon to the rescue! Look, it is very unlikely you have found a bug in Windows :-)